# Has a term emerged yet as the main one to refer to people who insist that COVID 19 is not real?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, neologisms

I'm sure I'm not the only one who has a couple of acquaintances on Facebook telling us how we're all being fooled and that COVID-19 is not real, or is just an average flu, etc.

Are people already favouring one term to refer to such people over other possible variations?

Here are some but not all possibilities:

- Covid denier?
- Coronavirus sceptic?
- Covid denialist?
- covidiot?
- Corona unbeliever?

One of these or something else? No clear leading term so far?

Comment: I have downvoted your question because entering the terms *Covid denier* and  *Coronavirus sceptic* or "something like that", into any reasonable search engine will give you some results.

Comment: @Greybeard: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109715/154292 - So which term is the main one?

Comment: I think  ***Covidiots*** is more likely  used for those who deny its existence and behave ignoring protections.

Comment: "Trumpette" would be my choice.

Comment: @user067531: Me too, but in other places where I asked people kept suggesting it so maybe some do use it for this?

Answer (score 3):

[Denialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIV/AIDS_denialism) has been used for another disease: HIV.

> HIV/AIDS *denialism* is the belief, contradicted by conclusive evidence, that human immunodeficiency virus (HIV) does not cause acquired immune deficiency syndrome (AIDS).

The people who engage in *denialism* are called *denialists*.

> In 2000, South Africa's President Thabo Mbeki invited several HIV/AIDS *denialists* to join his Presidential AIDS Advisory Panel.

Paul Krugman, in his imitable style, has a NYT Op-ed piece entitled "Covid-19 Brings Out All the Usual Zombies: Why *virus denial* resembles climate denial." [Source](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/28/opinion/coronavirus-trump-response.html)

Other terms may emerge, as the pandemic is still nascent.